# Nested Maybe<> will not executed when subscribing on the chain

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Hi,

In a RxJava chain, There are nested dependent Maybes meaning that the inner one will use the outer one results. Here the problem is when I `subscribe` on the chain, it will only cause the outer Maybe to be executed and the inner one will be ignored! Here is a sample:

```java
    redis.rxHgetall(key)
            .map(new Function<Response, List<M>>() {
                @Override
                public List<M> apply(@NonNull Response response) throws Exception {
                    response.getKeys().stream().forEach(new Consumer<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(String s) {
                            mList.add(new M(s, response.get(s).toString()));
                        }
                    });
                    return mList;
                }
            })
            .map(new Function<List<M>, List<M>>() {
                @Override
                public List<M> apply(@NonNull List<M> mList) throws Exception {
                    mList.stream().forEach(new Consumer<M>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(M m) {
                            final List<Property> propertyList = new ArrayList<>();
                            redis.rxHgetall(m.getName())
                                    .map(new Function<Response, M>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public M apply(@NonNull Response response) throws Exception {
                                            response.getKeys().stream().forEach(new Consumer<String>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void accept(String s) {
                                                    propertyList.add(
                                                            new Property(s,
                                                                    response.get(s).toString()));
                                                }
                                            });
                                            m.setProperties(propertyList);
                                            return m;
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    });
                    return mList;
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new MaybeObserver<List<M>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable disposable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull List<M> mList) {
                    resultList.add(new MGroup(m_group_id, mList));
                    future.complete(resultList);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable throwable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Here the **first** `flatMap` gets some keys from the Redis and then the **second** `flatMap` calls Redis again to get some values for the keys extracted on the **first** `flatMap`. When I subscribe to the chain, the first flatMap will be executed completely but the result of the `redis.rxHgetall` in second flatMap which is of type Maybe will not be executed!

I also tried subscribing to the Maybe on the second flatMap and it causes the inner Maybe to be executed but after the outer Maybe (in the first flatMap) and this is while I need to call `future.complete(resultList);` when both of the flatMaps are fully executed.

```java
map(new Function<List<M>, List<M>>() {
            @Override
            public List<M> apply(@NonNull List<M> mList) throws Exception {
                mList.stream().forEach(new Consumer<M>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(M m) {
                        final List<Property> propertyList = new ArrayList<>();
                        redis.rxHgetall(m.getName())
                                .map(new Function<Response, M>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public M apply(@NonNull Response response) throws Exception {
                                        response.getKeys().stream().forEach(new Consumer<String>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void accept(String s) {
                                                propertyList.add(
                                                        new Property(s,
                                                                response.get(s).toString()));
                                            }
                                        });
                                        m.setProperties(propertyList);
                                        return m;
                                    }
                                }).subscribe();
```

Comment: You keep using `Maybe.create` - why is that? Every time you use it, you could just use `Maybe.just(list)` instead, or it just shouldn't be used at all. The first flatMap looks like it should just be a `map` call, since you're not doing anything that requires a `Maybe`. Also, I think your problem is that you return a `Maybe.create` instead of returning the the chain that starts with the  inner `redist.rxHgetall()`. Because you never return it, it never gets subscribed to.

Comment: @dano Thanks. You are right. The Maybe.create was stupid! I removed them and updated the question. I also used map instead of flatmap. But still the same result. Could you describe more on how can I transform the chain to start with the inner `redist.rxHgetall()`, as the inner one are using the outer one's result.